# Sunspot SOLR KeywordTokenizer - search won't return proper results

Tags: ruby-on-rails, search, solr, sunspot

So I'm using sunspot in my rails project, and I'm indexing song names. **What I want to do is** when I do a search for a specific term (for example "lose yourself"), **in the top of my results list to appear the records that contain the exact match for the query** (with spaces and everything).

To do that I decided to define a new `fieldType` in the `schema.xml` using `KeywordTokenizerFactory` like this (I was planning to use it alongside the normal text field with the `StandardTokenizer`, use both of these and boost the results that came out using the `KeywordTokenized` field):

```
<fieldType name="text_exact" class="solr.TextField" omitNorms="false">
  <analyzer>
    <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.TrimFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

and adding a dynamic field like this (not sure it should be multivalued for this purpose, maybe someone can enlighten me on this too):

```
<dynamicField name="*_exact" stored="false" type="text_exact" multiValued="true" indexed="true"/>
```

Now, in my `song.rb` file i have this in the `searchable` configuration:

```
text :song_name do
  self.name
end

text :song_name_exact, as: :song_name_exact do
  self.name
end
```

The problem is that when I try to search by using the `song_name_exact` field I get **no** results if my query contains spaces (so if i have a song called `foo` and I search for `foo` it will find it, but if i have one called `foo bar` and search for `foo bar`, the search query returns no results.

So first of all, I would ask if my approach to this is correct, and why isn't the search over the field with keyword tokenizer working properly?

Comment: What does your search query use like - you'll want a similar analyser to be used for that too

Comment: If you're asking if I use the same analyzer for querying and indexing, the answer is yes (if you look at the fieldtype configuration you'll see that I haven't separated the query and the index analyzers, so they both use the same stuff)

Comment: What if you "wrap" the term in quotes before the search but using a regular text field? If you also need the non-exact matches you could do 2 searches...

Comment: I didn't try wrapping the term in quotes.. and also this seems like a hack.. I mean why bend sunspot/solr, when this is the way it would be supposed to work

Comment: Are you using standard query parser or the dismax query parser?

Answer (score 1):

The reason why search for "lose yourself" only doesn't provide a result is that the token generated by **KeywordTokenizerFactory** is "lose youself" but the queryParse used by sunspot split your query into two tokens "lose" and "yourself"

**Solution**

so you should search for the whole phrase by adding double quotes to the search to be **"\"lose yourself\""**